# AJAX Call from Javascript does not work the first time but works each successive time

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using an AJAX call within a javascript function to populate a SELECT input.  This script does not work the first time but works as I intend it to each subsequent time that it is called.  The relevant code follows:

```
function getXMLHttp()
{
    var xmlHttp;

    try
    {
        //Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        //Internet Explorer
        try
        {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            try
            {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!")
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}

function populateEntries(menu, userName, entryRow)
{

    var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if ((xmlHttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlHttp.status == 200) && (xmlHttp.responseText == ""))
        {
            window.alert("There are no records to view!");      }
        else if ((xmlHttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlHttp.status == 200))
        {
            response = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "getUsers.php", true)
    xmlHttp.send(null);

    ADDITIONAL UNRELATED CODE FOLLOWS ....

}
```

I've checked to see if the "response" is being passed from the AJAX call during the first function call and it is but it is not being passed out of the function for further use in the code that follows except on subsequent function calls.  Can anyone tell me why this is happening?  Your help will be very much appreciated.  Before you tell me that this can be done with jquery, please understand that I need to do it with javascript.

Comment: And where is `response` being used, outside the onreadystate callback? Remember that it's async!

Comment: I don't see a `var response` in your code. How do you initialize or use `response`? In what scope? It might be related with your issue.

Comment: adeneo - response is parsed later in the same function to create a multi-dimensional array that populates the Select options.  Can you expand on what you mean by async?

Comment: faiakism - It's always the simple things that catch you up, he said sheepishly.  Unfortunately declaring the variable response earlier in the function made things worse.  My function now only works if I add an alert box to stop processing before the function continues and populates the select box.